# is there any way to search on while loop populated data with angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, html

I have a situtation where my previous code is 2000 to 3000 lines so i don't want `angular` `$http` to `populate` all data on my page. rather i want `search` functionality on `php` `populated` data.

**Question:**   how to include `angular` search functionality on `php populated data`?

**my search button:**

```
<input type="search" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="search()"/>
```

**my controller:**

```
myApp.controller('clickListenerCtrl',function($scope,$http){

  $scope.search = function(){

      console.log($scope.searchText);  // im able get typed text
  }
});
```

**my while loop:**

```
<table ng-controller="clickListenerCtrl">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php while($row = ......){ ?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>
</table>
```

**In core angularjs we could do like this(solution):**

```
<table ng-controller="clickListenerCtrl">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="x in data | filter:searchText">
    <td>{{x.id}}</td>
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

please help me thanks in advance!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: you want to use the angular or php for search?

Comment: angular for search

Comment: for `populated` front end

Comment: Why dont you use http service to get same data from angularjs. So that you get control on data

Answer (score 0):

Your controller could be like this-

```
            myApp.controller('clickListenerCtrl',function($scope,$http){

            $scope.search = function(){
            console.log($scope.searchText);  // im able get typed text                      

            //use ajax to call php to fetch serach results and then 
            // display the same in view
            // then you will not need filter in ng-repeat

            $http({
               url: "search.php",
               method: 'POST',
               headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
               data: 'searchText='+$scope.searchText
           }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

               console.log(data);
               $scope.data = data;


           }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               $scope.status = status;
               console.log("error");
           });  

          };
        });
```